# How To Retrieve Item Specific Fields Of JSON using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

This is the following json object I am getting:

```
{ "1":"data", "2":"data", "3":"data", "4":"data"}
```

data is an int being recieved from a sensor.
1,2,3&4 are the different sensor values.

My Api Class:

```
public interface DetailsAPI {
@GET("/SET/team1/retrieve_data")
Call<ResponseBody> getpost();
}
```

My Main Class Where I Call This:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ip.ip).build();

    final DetailsAPI api = retrofit.create(DetailsAPI.class);
    final Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            api.getpost().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    try {

                        String res = response.body().string();
                        sensor1.setText(res);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            // upadte textView here
            handler.postDelayed(this,100); // set time here to refresh textView
        }
    });
```

When it is printed I get:

```
{ "1":"data", "2":"data", "3":"data", "4":"data"}
```

I want to be able to specify what 1 , 2 ,3 and 4 is without the {"" :""}

The desired output I would like would be something like

```
Light : data
Sound : data
Temp : data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add gson-converter to your project and Create your pojo class as:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SensorData{

@SerializedName("1")
@Expose
private String sensor1;
@SerializedName("2")
@Expose
private String sensor2;
@SerializedName("3")
@Expose
private String sensor3;
@SerializedName("4")
@Expose
private String sensor4;

public String getSensor1() {
return sensor1;
}

public void setSensor1(String sensor1) {
this.sensor1= sensor1;
}

public String getSensor2() {
return sensor2;
}

public void setSensor2(String sensor2) {
this.sensor2= sensor2;
}

public String getSensor3() {
return sensor3;
}

public void setSensor3(String sensor3) {
this.sensor3= sensor3;
}

public String getSensor4() {
return sensor4;
}

public void setSensor4(String sensor4) {
this.sensor4= sensor4;
}

}
```

**API class:**

```
public interface DetailsAPI {
@GET("/SET/team1/retrieve_data")
Call<SensorData> getPost();
}
```

setup **Retrofit callback** as:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(url)
                        .client(httpClient)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

DetailsAPI api = retrofit.create(DetailsAPI.class);
api.getPost().enqueue(new Callback<SensorData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SensorData> call, 
        Response<SensorData> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ");
            SensorData sensorData = response.body();
            System.out.println("Light :"+sensorData.getSensor1());
            System.out.println("Sound :"+sensorData.getSensor2());
            System.out.println("Temp :"+sensorData.getSensor3());
            System.out.println("Fire :"+sensorData.getSensor4());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SensorData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I am getting an error of Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add GSON Convertor to retrofit.

create a class like this

```
class Data{
    String key;
    String value;
}
```

make your Interface like this

```
@GET("group/{id}/users") Call<List<Data>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);
```

your retrofit callback

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ip.ip).build();
final DetailsAPI api = retrofit.create(DetailsAPI.class);
final Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable(){ @Override public void run() { 
api.getpost().enqueue(new Callback<List<Data>>() { 
@Override public void onResponse(Call<List<Data>> call, Response<List<Data>> response) {
 try { List<Data> res = response.body()
// after this us can use this list to iterate over.
 }
 catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } } 
@Override public void onFailure(Call<List<Data>> call, Throwable t) { } }); // upadte textView here handler.postDelayed(this,100); // set time here to refresh textView } });
```

Answer (score 1):

So your call is stated to get ResponseBody object as a response. You can create your own response class and replace ResponseBody.

You can find some calls here : 
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

It looks like:

```
@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);
```

It will also affect callback, you will get your class as a response.

Comment: Could you please help me in how I would go about doing this?

Comment: First of all copy your response and check it with any json view on the web. Next, if that json is ok you can create pojo from it and copy those classes to your project.

Comment: This might help: http://f2prateek.com/2017/04/21/unwrapping-data-with-retrofit-2/

Comment: I try to create the getters and setters but then I get an error Cannot resolve symbol 'jsonInclude' .... and a few more of those sort of errors

Answer (score 0):

Change model class for response like this

```
public class ResponseBody {

@SerializedName("1")
@Expose
private String _1;
@SerializedName("2")
@Expose
private String _2;
@SerializedName("3")
@Expose
private String _3;
@SerializedName("4")
@Expose
private String _4;

public String get1() {
return _1;
}

public void set1(String _1) {
this._1 = _1;
}

public String get2() {
return _2;
}

public void set2(String _2) {
this._2 = _2;
}

public String get3() {
return _3;
}

public void set3(String _3) {
this._3 = _3;
}

public String get4() {
return _4;
}

public void set4(String _4) {
this._4 = _4;
}
}
```

Then change your retrofit onResponse contents like this

```
    try {

             ResponseBody res = response.body().string();
             sensor1.setText("Light :"+res.get1());
             sensor2.setText("Sound :"+res.get2()); //create textview sensor2
             sensor3.setText("Temp :"+res.get3()); //create textview sensor3
             } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
```